# Regular Expression to extract the digits comes after 36th character in a String

Tags: regex, jmeter

In jmeter, I need to extract digits which comes after 36th character.

Example

```
Response:  {"data":{"paymentId":"DOM1234567890111243"}}
```

I need to extract :11243 (Sometimes it will be only 1 or 2 or 3 or 4 digits)

Right boundary : DOM12345678901 Keeps changing too.But the right boundary length will be 36 charters always.

Any help will be higly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Your response data seems to be [JSON](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON) therefore I wouldn't rely on this "36 characters" as it's format might be different.

I would suggest extracting this `paymentId` value first and then apply a regular expression onto this `DOMxxx` bit.

1. Add [JSR223 PostProcessor](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_PostProcessor) as a child of the request which returns the above data
2. Put the following code into "Script" area:

   ```
   def dom = new groovy.json.JsonSlurper().parse(prev.getResponseData()).data.paymentId
   log.info("DOM: " + dom)
   def myValue = ((dom =~ ".{14}(\\d+)")[0][1]) as String
   log.info("myValue: " + myValue)

   vars.put("myValue", myValue)
   ```
3. That's it, you should be able to access the extracted data as `${myValue}` where required.

   [image]

More information:

- [Groovy: Parsing and producing JSON](http://groovy-lang.org/json.html)
- [Groovy: Match Operator](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/documentation/core-operators.html#_match_operator)
- [Apache Groovy - Why and How You Should Use It](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/groovy-new-black)

Comment: Thanks for the information for extracting only the DOM value. It worked

Answer (score 1):

If there isn't anything else in the string you're checking, you could use something like:

```
.{36}(\d+)
```

The first group of this regex will be the number you're looking for.

Test and explanation: https://regex101.com/r/iDOO8T/2